# Get Python Version with Bash Script

Tags: bash, python, script

I have a script that gets the python version from clients. The command in bash is:

```
pythonVer=$(ssh $user@$ip "python --version")
```

But this command shows the python version on stdout (my terminal that connects to clients) but I cannot assign this value to a variable. Just one server allows this, so when I tried to write this var to a file, I can see only one version in this file, other version numbers are in only my terminal.

What is this issue about the "python" command? How can I assign the client's python version to my var named `pythonVer`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems python outputs its version to stderr, not stdout. So, redirect stderr to stdout in order to capture it

```
pythonVer=$(ssh "$user"@"$ip" 'python --version 2>&1')
```

or

```
pythonVer=$(ssh "$user"@"$ip" 'python --version' 2>&1)
```